# How do I copy a sketch from the Geometer's sketchpad to a question or to an answer

Tags: support, images

I use The Geometer's Sketchpad (GSP v 5) and don't seem to be able to cut and paste drawings from it into a question or an answer.

The program allows to select all and copy:

"This Edit menu command places a copy of each selected object on the clipboard. The contents of the clipboard can then be pasted into the same sketch, a different sketch, or into another application.

The keyboard shortcut for Copy is Ctrl+C (Windows) or C (Mac).

If you copy objects and paste them into the same sketch or a different sketch, Sketchpad pastes the actual selected objects.

If you copy objects and paste them into a different application, Sketchpad pastes a picture of the selected objects."

but it just doesn't seem to work :(

can somebody give better instructions.

Comment: Are you trying to paste these objects directly into the SE editor? or some other program?

Comment: directly into the SE Editor

Comment: I would highly doubt this would ever work: the editor here expects text input, and even pasting a .jpeg or .gif results in pasting the filename.  Try to first paste into some sort of paint program, save the image, and then insert the image into your post.

Comment: Try opening the "insert image" dialog and paste then, this works from regular image manipulation programs at least.

Comment: @MadScientist: I never thought of trying that (and neither have I ever fully read that dialogue, it appears).

Comment: @ArthurFischer, do you know if Geometer's Sketchpad has its own command to save one of its images as a jpeg on its host computer? If I were the company selling such a program, I would include that. If so, that will probably be the best quality image and the fewest keystrokes/clicks to be able to, later, upload to MSE.

Comment: @WillJagy: I know (virtually) nothing about Geometer's Sketchpad; otherwise I probably could have posted an answer of some sort.  I've tried to figure out what "export to image" features it has (without downloading a free trial) but so far no luck.  You're right that it would appear to be an obvious feature, but the only thing I could really go on was the OP, which only indicated the copy-and-paste functionality.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, thanks. I've never tried G.S. I think the company that wrote it is Key Curriculum, a mile or two from my apartment, and then they got bought by a big publisher.

Comment: @ArthurFischer as far as i can follow it GSP only saves  in  *.gsp or in *.emf (Enhanced Metafile+) format, . emf is some kind of graphic format. it does support copy and paste via the cilpboard , but not drag and drop, and math exchange only seem to support drag and drop and not copy aand paste ?

Comment: @MadScientist >> Try opening the "insert image" dialog and paste then, this works from regular image manipulation programs at least.<< it says it only supports drag and drop, and not copy and paste (if it ony did I would be happy)

Comment: @Willemien The "insert image" dialog does support copy & paste, the only question is if your program support copying to the clipboard in a suitable format.

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate step for me, as I said in comment at [How to construct three mutually orthogonal circles in stereographic projection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637449/how-to-construct-three-mutually-orthogonal-circles-in-stereographic-projection)  is to save some image as a jpeg on my home computer. Then an answer window, or a question window, has a little icon of a painting on the upper left. Clicking on that gives a little screen that allows one to browse on one's own computer.  Then, having selected the correct one, confirm that we wish to upload. I've never had any trouble using that.

So, the question for those who know becomes, does Geometer's SketchPad have a feature to save an image as a jpeg on the computer on which it is being used?

I see; looking at Arthur Fischer's first comment, the two options, slightly different, are (A) Geometer's SketchPad does have an option to make a jpeg of one of its images and save that with a name on the computer (B) G.S. does not have such an option or it works poorly, in which case we are looking for other programs "paint" that can make a jpeg of anything on the computer screen. In my case, I can make a jpeg of the entire web browser using a Linux command "import." This included the tab listings at the top of Firefox in my case.